# Could someone create a simple moving average (lets say 20 SMA) function without using a prebuilt function

Tags: r

Please help me create a simple moving average function without using a prebuilt function in R.

This is a question from our teacher.

```
This is the sample of the data set, it has 250,000 rows.
Date    Time    Open    High    Low Close
5/28/1999   7:30    1.5972  1.5982  1.5964  1.5978
5/28/1999   8:00    1.5975  1.5979  1.5959  1.5973
5/28/1999   8:30    1.5972  1.5994  1.5971  1.5982
5/28/1999   9:00    1.5984  1.5999  1.5981  1.5986
5/28/1999   9:30    1.5988  1.5999  1.5983  1.5994
5/28/1999   10:00   1.5996  1.6 1.5979  1.5982
5/28/1999   10:30   1.5983  1.5985  1.5962  1.5972


 i'm not sure where to start...
```

Comment: What functions can be used?

Comment: Are you intending to use a `for` loop to do this? Dismissing the "grossly inefficient" commentary on that approach (this is for learning, after all), I think you can iterate over each value in the vector (use `function(x, k) { for (index in seq_along(x)) {...} }`), building a vector out to your "`k`ernel width". Always append the current value, then if the length of the vector is greater than your "kernel width" vector, remove the first one. Again, inefficient, but it is one way to to moving-window operations. (Once you have this window-vector, use `sum`, `mean`, whatever ...)

Comment: One thing I'd caution against: don't write a function that operates on a frame ... write one that operates on a vector, and then figure out how to apply that function to specific (or all?) columns of a frame.

Comment: i can use anything as long as i build the function myself. i just cant use quantmod's sma prebuilt.